# jQuery Sortable Rearrange Input Names and Sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to rearrange all the input fields' name within a field group with current position of the field group after sorting the group with jQuery sortable. I just have to rearrange the position number (0 based) in input fields' name that are `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, `[4]`, `[4]` etc.

Here is the basic HTML

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="field-group">
        <div class="accordian-header"></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="section[0]text" value="">
            <textarea name="section[0]textarea"></textarea>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[0]check" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div class="accordian-header"></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="section[1]text" value="">
            <textarea name="section[1]textarea"></textarea>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[1]check" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div class="accordian-header"></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="section[2]text" value="">
            <textarea name="section[2]textarea"></textarea>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[2]check" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div class="accordian-header"></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="section[3]text" value="">
            <textarea name="section[3]textarea"></textarea>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[3]check" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div class="accordian-header"></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="section[4]text" value="">
            <textarea name="section[4]textarea"></textarea>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[4]check" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, here is the closest I got so far.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('.sortable' ).each(function() {
        $(this).accordion({
            header: '> .field-group > .accordian-header',
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            animate: 300,
        }).sortable({
            revert: true,
            axis: 'y',
            handle: '.accordian-header',
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.item.children( '.accordian-header' ).triggerHandler( 'focusout' );
                $( this ).accordion( 'refresh' );
                $.map($(this).find('.field-group'), function(el) {
                    var inputs = $(this).find('input');
                    inputs.each(function () {
                        this.name = this.name.replace(/(\[\0-9\])/, '[' + $(el).index() + ']');  
                    });
                    //console.log( $(el).index() );
                });
            },
        });
    });    
});
```

I also tried many answers from here, but no luck. Here is the latest fiddle I made with my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/itsabhik/oj3awz78/3/

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `$(".field-group").each()` instead. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fhmgrjuq/

**Snippet**

```
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.children('.accordian-header').triggerHandler('focusout');
        $(this).accordion('refresh');

        var i = 0;
        $('.field-group').each(function(k, el) {
          $(el).find("input").attr("name", 'section[' + i + ']text');
          $(el).find("textarea").attr("name", 'section[' + i + ']textarea');
          $(el).find("checkbox").attr("name", 'section[' + i + ']check');
          i++;
        });
      }
```

I suspect it can be improved. This works as you described it. After each sort, the index number in the `name` attribute of each input element is updated to reflect the new order.

Comment: Thanks, that nearly served my purpose as the names of inputs are dynamic. So, I have to made some modifications to the code. However, that indeed was a headstart for me. Upvoted.